# Can't insert unicode into mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am having a problem with mysql when I tried to insert unicode (chinese here) in mysql, for example, I want to insert:

```
insert into site_parameter(name) values("测试");
```

however in mysql terminal, it become:

```
mysql> insert into site_parameter(name) values("");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

I can't even type chinese under the mysql terminal.

here is my.conf

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

I have checked the collation:

```
mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+


mysql> show create table  site_parameter;

| site_parameter | CREATE TABLE `site_parameter` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=388 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Devart said, the link below does provide the solution:

https://superuser.com/questions/55224/change-the-default-codepage-from-latin1-to-utf8-on-a-linux-machine

Here is the solution detail:

Edit /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local and add your locale to the list of supported locales if it isn't there already, eg:

```
en_US UTF-8
```

Regenerate the supported locales on your machine:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Open /etc/default/locale and check if LANG and LANGUAGE are changed:

```
LANG="en_US"
LANGUAGE="en_US:UTF-8"
```

if they are not, you can manually update them now.

reboot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a charset property in console window (CMD).

You can check current or set another with **chcp** command -

```
>chcp
>will output current

>chcp 65001
>will set utf-8
```

Some information about this command - [Chcp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490874.aspx).

Comment: unfortunately I am using ubuntu

Comment: I have found this one - http://superuser.com/questions/55224/change-the-default-codepage-from-latin1-to-utf8-on-a-linux-machine. Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks, that does solve my pb! I'll add the solution later.

Comment: @seaguest Welcome!